# How to use different colorscheme and syntax highlighting in vim?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

Suppose I want to use this colorscheme: https://github.com/NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme

I copied the `PaperColor.vim` file into `.vim/colors` and made my `.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
colorscheme PaperColor
background=light
```

Now, I want to use this syntax highlighting for haskell files: https://github.com/raichoo/haskell-vim/tree/master/syntax

There are two syntax highlighting files. Which one am I supposed to use, and where do it put them?

Do I put it in `./vim/syntax` and vim auto-loads all files in `./vim/syntax` folder?

It seems like to load `haskell.vim` automatically. But doesn't load `cabal.vim`.

Wondering if it only loads `haskell.vim` when I open `*.hs` files? I'm trying to make it like that.

Can vim load multiple syntax files at once?

Comment: Next time, please try to keep your question focused by asking a single question. Answer ended up going too long... But hopefully it'll be useful to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use different colorscheme and syntax highlighting in vim?

Colorscheme and syntax highlighting are complementary in Vim, so you typically use one of each.

The colorscheme will define what color is applied to each type of element (such as Keyword, Identifier, String, Number, etc.)

While the syntax highlighting (for a specific filetype, typically a programming language) will define how to identify those elements for that language (for example, with a list of reserved words or regular expressions to delimit the specific items.)

> Suppose I want to use [papercolor] colorscheme. 
>   I copied the `PaperColor.vim` file into `.vim/colors` and made my `.vimrc`: [...]

That's one possible way to install it, but I really recommend using a plugin manager instead! Read on.

> Now, I want to use this syntax highlighting for haskell files:

So here you'll see more the value of a plugin  manager! Since technically you're supposed to copy *all* the `*.vim` files from every subdirectory into the corresponding subdirectory of `~/.vim`, but that quickly becomes pretty messy if you want to install many plugins. (Manually unpacking them means all the files would mix together!)

I really recommend using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug), since it works great on Vim 7, Vim 8, Neovim, etc. Vim 8 and Neovim support "native" plugins but you need to manually handle the docs, so you benefit from using vim-plug on them too.

See the README file for installation instructions (you just need to download one file), then update your `~/.vimrc` to list the two plugins you're interested on:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme'
Plug 'raichoo/haskell-vim'
call plug#end()
```

Then start Vim and run the `:PlugInstall` command. Done!

---

If you use a plugin manager, you don't need to *care* about the other details... But in case you want to understand how it works, here it goes:

> There are two syntax highlighting files. Which one am I supposed to use, and where do it put them?

They are for different `filetype`s and they're loaded when a specific `filetype` is set.

> Do I put it in `./vim/syntax` and vim auto-loads all files in `./vim/syntax` folder?

Yes, Vim will load a file named `xyz.vim` whenever `filetype` is set to *xyz*.

So if you open a buffer, type some text and then use a command such as `:setf haskell` it will load `haskell.vim` from `~/.vim/syntax`.

(See `:help 'filetype'` and `:help :setf` for more details.)

> It seems like to load `haskell.vim` automatically. But doesn't load `cabal.vim`.

That will be used for files of type `cabal`, so using `:setf cabal` will use that syntax highlighting configuration. (i don't know much about Haskell and Cabal but I imagine they're related files, with somewhat different syntax and distinct file extensions.)

> Wondering if it only loads `haskell.vim` when I open `*.hs` files? I'm trying to make it like that.

The default Vim configuration already ships commands that will set up the correct filetype (haskell, cabal) for common extensions such as `*.hs`.

The haskell-vim plugin also ships a `ftdetect/haskell.vim` script that configures it for additional extensions, with the following commands:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.hsc set filetype=haskell
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.bpk set filetype=haskell
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.hsig set filetype=haskell
```

As you can see, that's how plugins attach syntax (and indent, key mappings, etc.) for specific file types.

> Can vim load multiple syntax files at once?

Yes, but that's quite unusual...

Here's an example from `:help 'filetype'`:

```
    When a dot appears in the value then this separates two filetype
    names.  Example:
        /* vim: set filetype=c.doxygen : */ 
    This will use the "c" filetype first, then the "doxygen" filetype.
```

Answer (score 1):

To use colorscheme:

1. put it into `.vim/colors/PaperColor.vim`
2. run `:color PaperColor
3. run `:set background=light` to make it use light background
4. if it works, persist settings in your `.vimrc`

```
color PaperColor
set background=light
```

To use haskell syntax from mentioned package without following installation instructions given on repo readme :) :

1. put it into `/vim/syntax/haskell.vim` (from the repo folder `/syntax/`)
2. now there is also file type detection located in repo's `/ftdetect/` folder (https://github.com/raichoo/haskell-vim/tree/master/ftdetect), get `haskell.vim` from there and put it into your local `.vim/ftdetect/haskell.vim`. File type detection makes vim load haskell syntax automatically (simplified explanation)

But I really suggest to use installation method described in a README file. Either using pathogen or manually. (or using any package manager)